# Expansion using variables bash

Tags: bash

I have a variable:

```
rules=L002,L003
```

This rules variable denotes the files to copy from /usr/lib/vera++/scrpts/rules directory. The extension for the files is .tcl.

I am doing something like:

```
cp -r /usr/lib/vera++/scripts/rules/{${rules}}.tcl .
```

What goes wrong is that ${rules} is treated completely as a string. But bash should translate that into:

```
cp -r /usr/lib/vera++/scripts/rules/{L002,L003}.tcl .
```

Comment: This is only a duplicate, if `rules` contains integer sequences. I am not sure, if `L002`,`L003` can be counted as an integer sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to take an argument and make a command from this argument is to use `eval` command. In your case whole script will look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

rules=L002,L003
eval "cp -r /usr/lib/vera++/scripts/rules/{${rules}}.tcl ."
```